# What are the magic $-prefixed variables in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, variables

I've seen magic variables like this used in Ruby. `$_` `$'` `$0`

Is there a complete reference for what all of them mean and how they are set?

Comment: What a ridiculous reason to close the question as "off-topic".

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Their name is `global variables`. There are several different references.

You can get a full list by calling the method `Kernel#global_variables`

```
puts global_variables
```

Ruby also includes a file called "[English.rb](http://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/English.rb)" in the standard library which provides an in-depth explanation of several global variables.

Also, there's (an archived version of) "[Cryptic Ruby Global Variables and Their Meanings](https://web.archive.org/web/20160823183543/http://jimneath.org/2010/01/04/cryptic-ruby-global-variables-and-their-meanings.html)".

Finally, the Ruby Programming wikibook has a "[Predefined Variables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Reference/Predefined_Variables)" reference.

Comment: Here's [another reference](http://jimneath.org/2010/01/04/cryptic-ruby-global-variables-and-their-meanings.html). The one at the end of the post above is broken.

Comment: something neat with that is that you can see the value of all env variables, e.g. `global_variables.map { |v| puts "#{v.inspect} #{eval("#{v}").inspect rescue 'nope'}" }`

Comment: As of today, `English.rb` actually got extracted into a gem call `English`, so you might want to take a look here instead https://github.com/ruby/English/blob/master/lib/English.rb

Answer (score 4):

They are called "global variables" (complete list at the bottom of the page): http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/globalvars.html

Comment: thanks for this. I have seen this link but I never really revisited it because of how incomplete of a reference it was. I'll give you +1 for linking relevant information, anyhow :)

Answer (score 2):

The Ruby documentation used to be very class orientated. In recent versions of Ruby however there are [rdoc files](https://ruby-doc.org/core/) about literals, precedence, syntax, [globals](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/globals_rdoc.html)  and much more.