# What do $&, $', $1 etc. mean in Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I'm confused about how the `$` variables work in this part of EventMachine code (`strip_op` is a `String#sub` method):

```
def receive_data(data)
      @buf = @buf ? @buf << data : data

      while (@buf && !@closing)
        case @parse_state
        when AWAITING_CONTROL_LINE
          case @buf
          when PUB_OP
            ctrace('PUB OP', strip_op($&)) if NATSD::Server.trace_flag?
            return connect_auth_timeout if @auth_pending
            @buf = $'
            @parse_state = AWAITING_MSG_PAYLOAD
            @msg_sub, @msg_reply, @msg_size = $1, $3, $4.to_i
```

What are the meanings for `$&`, `$'`, `$1`, etc.?

Comment: See this: http://jimneath.org/2010/01/04/cryptic-ruby-global-variables-and-their-meanings.html

Comment: These are documented here and there around the internets, but their form makes it difficult to search for. Check "[Magic $-prefixed variables in Ruby; is there a complete reference somewhere?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746615/magic-prefixed-variables-in-ruby-is-there-a-complete-reference-somewhere)" and http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/ruby/stdlib/libdoc/English/rdoc/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those hold parts of the last regex match. `$&`: the matched substring, `$'`: the substring that follows the match, `$1`: the first captured substring of the match.