# Ruby - preserve regex globals over function calls

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm wondering how to preserve the value of $1, $~ etc. over function calls. I'm writing some functions that accept regular expressions as arguments, and it would be useful to have these available after the function is called (I guess I could pass out the MatchData along with the other return value, but this way seems more like the Ruby way...).

Here's a short script that demonstrates the problem:

```
def foo()
    "abc123" =~ /(\d+)/
    puts "I see $1: #{$1}"
end

foo()
puts "I see $1: #{$1}"
```

For me, this prints out:

```
I see $1: 123
I see $1:
```

As an aside, is there some canonical name for these types of variables? Just calling them "regex globals" makes it hard to search for on Google!

Comment: It's not ruby way. It's perl way. Don't even try to do it. Passing state in global variables is bad, m'kay? :)

Comment: BTW: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3747135/125816

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would return `$1` from the method rather than storing them in a global variable.

```
def foo()
    "abc123" =~ /(\d+)/
    $1
end

puts "blah is #{foo}"
```

Comment: I can see your reasoning, but using $1, $2 etc. fits more closely with the Ruby way; it'll make it more transparent if users can use $1, $2 afterwards like with any other regex. In essence, the function I'm writing is logically like using `=~`, but I just get the data from somewhere else, so it makes sense to make it behave like `=~` in that way.