# What does *$< mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I was analyzing my friend's code, and I saw this little snippet:

```
n,a=*$<
```

I can't figure out what it means - I've searched on many sites, but they don't seem to recognize the special characters.

Comment: `$<` is ARGF and `*` is splat.

Comment: What does ARGF mean?

Comment: Check also https://stackoverflow.com/a/3747135/846163 and run the snippet within irb. The code take the input from STDIN and takes the first two lines into `n` and `a`.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$<` is ARGF. From ruby's standard docummentation:

> ARGF is a stream designed for use in scripts that process files given as command-line arguments or passed in via STDIN.

A super good explanation [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rubys-argf)

`*` is splat operator.

You are assigning to `a` and `n` what's inside ARGF/STDIN at that point.

Example:

```
raducroitoru@dotix ~$ cat a.txt                                         
a
b
c

raducroitoru@dotix ~$ cat a.rb                                          
a, n = *$<
puts "a is: #{a}"
puts "n is: #{n}"

raducroitoru@dotix ~$ ruby a.rb a.txt                                   
a is: a
n is: b
```

Comment: More specifically, `*` invokes `ARGF#to_a` which is an alias for [`ARGF#readlines`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/ARGF.html#method-i-readlines), so `n, a = *$<` is equivalent to `n, a = ARGF.readlines`